# Spinning words, but cannot return result in correct order

Tags: c++

I'm writing a function that takes a string, and reverses all the space-separated words that are longer than 5 characters.

e.g. the expected output for an input string

> "Hey fellow warriors"

should be

> "Hey wollef sroirraw"

Currently with my code I'm getting the result

> "sroirraw Hey wollef"

which spins the words that are longer than 5 characters, however they don't print in the correct order.

I assume that this is happening because of how the assignment of the string being split is done and how they are printed. I initialized `y` to `x` cause initially I was not using a vector to store the words. I was hoping to run a check if words were longer than 5 then it would reverse it, add a blank space, continue the loop for the string, join the string and return the joint string.

```
std::string spinWords(const std::string &str)
{
  std:: string x = "";
  std:: string y = "";
  std::vector<std::string> words;
  for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
    if (str[i] == ' '){
        if (x.length() > 5){
            std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
        }
        words.push_back(x);
        x= "";
    }
    x = x + str[i];
  }

  if (x.length() > 5){
    std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
  }
  y = x;
  for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++){
    y = y + words[j] + " ";
  }

  return y;
}

int main(){
  std::cout << "\n\n" << spinWords("Welcome");
  std::cout << "\n\n" << spinWords("Hey fellow warriors");
}
```

Comment: I got `emocleW` and `sroirraw Hey wollef`.  Looks spun to me.  What kind of spinning are you expecting?

Comment: @Eljay, I was hoping for it to print the string in the same order as queried. So, it would return the result of "Hey fellow warriors" as "Hey wollef sroirraw".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some problems with your approach.

1. You probably don't want to consider spaces as part of words, so you should't add current symbol when it is `' '`:

```cpp
if (str[i] == ' ')
{
    //...
}
else // move it to else block
{
    x = x + str[i];
}
```

2. Following your logic, you forgot to add the last word to your collection, if it is not empty:

```cpp
// we add probably last word only if it is not empty
//empty ~ length() == 0 
if(!x.empty())
{
    if (x.length() > 5)
    {
        std::reverse(x.begin(), x.end());
    }

    words.push_back(x);
}

//Why this assigment?  
//y = x;
for (int j = 0; j < words.size(); j++)
{
    // use += for optimal string allocation
    y += words[j] + " ";
}
```

Some improvements:
You can use std::stringstream to split string by spaces returns etc:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

std::istringstream iss(str);
for (std::string word; iss >> word; )
{
    if (word.length() > 5)
    {
        std::reverse(word.begin(), word.end());
    }
    words.push_back(word);
}
```

You may also want to optimise string `y` internal reallocation. So you can accumulate overall size of all words in existing loop and reserve some memory for your result: `y.reserve(totalLength);` (actual for large input string)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Some of the things in this code were experimental. For example I was not using Vectors initially and y was just a container for the reversed words. Which I later realized was too inefficient, and it was just left there after. I am going to try stringstream approach, I haven't learnt that bit yet. Thank you once again.